# Не могу декодировать JSON в Swift

Tags: json, ios, xcode, swift, swift4

Пытаюсь декодировать JSON с моего сайта в мобильном приложении на Swift (xCode).

Пример JSON возращаемого с сайта можно вот:

```
    {
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": 98,
          "title": "Что представляет из себя Hackintosh?",
          "author": "Юрий Потапов",
          "excerpt": "В школе на информатике всем нам говорили, что существует такая операционная система(далее – ОС) как MacOS (Macintosh), и она не устанавливается на обычные PC, предоставляется только с компьютерами Apple. Что, естественно, бред. Эту прекрасную операционную систему можно установить на любой PC! Я один из обладателей этой операционной системы на обычном компьютере, и хочу рассказать об этом.",
          "date": "29.09.2018",
          "cover": "http:\/\/mubiridziri.ru\/blog\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/09\/cover-2.jpg"
        },
        {
          "id": 86,
          "title": "Созерцая свое творение.",
          "author": "Юрий Потапов",
          "excerpt": "Первый раз о программировании я узнал лет в двенадцать, когда, собственно, и начал этим интересоваться. С тех пор, я много раз сидел в восторге от того, что сделал. Когда смотришь на рабочую созданную тобой систему, ощущаешь душевную радость. А представляете, что вы будете чувствовать, когда поймете, что ваша система еще и людям помогает, м?",
          "date": "22.09.2018",
          "cover": null
        }
      ]
    }
```

Функция Swift:

```
    func getPosts() {
            let url = URL(string: "http://mubiridziri.ru/blog/api.php?request=1")!
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

                guard let data = data else {
                    print("Error: No data to decode")
                    return
                }

                guard let blog = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Blog.self, from: data) else {
                    print("Error: Couldn't decode data into Blog");
                    return
                }

                for article in blog.articles {
                    print("- \(article.title)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

Структура:

```
    struct Blog: Decodable {
            let articles: [Article]

            enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
                case articles = "posts"
            }
        }

        struct Article: Decodable {
            let id: Int
            let title: String
            let excerpt: String
            let date: String
            let cover: String

        }
```

Возвращается в консоль:

```
    print("Error: Couldn't decode data into Blog");
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сам только изучаю swift, по этому не могу сказать, что мое решение является единственно правильным или самым верным из всех возможных. Но распарсить ваши данные можно таким вот способом:

```
func parse() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://mubiridziri.ru/blog/api.php?request=1") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        guard error == nil else { return }

        do {
            let parse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Blog.self, from: data)
            guard let _parse = parse.posts else { return }

            for one in _parse {
                print(one)
            }


        } catch let error {
            print("ERROR - \(error)")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Структура:

```
import Foundation


struct Blog: Decodable {
    let posts: [Article]?
}

struct Article: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let title: String?
    let excerpt: String?
    let date: String?
    let cover: String?

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли!